# How do I use the current version of aurelia-validation?

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to follow an aurelia (validation) tutorial. However, I know for a fact it needs to be updated. Even so, I thought that with the docs I would be able to figure out how to make it work, which is not happening.

The original code goes like this:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {Validation} from "aurelia-validation";

@inject(Validation)
export class Edit {

    constructor(validation) {
        this.validation = validation.on(this)
            .ensure("movie.title")
                .isNotEmpty()
            .ensure("movie.releaseYear")
                .isNumber();
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore. I get an injection error when trying to get **validation** into the constructor.

I went to the docs and there doesn't seem to exist a **Validation** symbol anymore.

I tried injecting **ValidationRules** and **Validator** into my class but none support **ensure** or **on** methods.

I tried following the flow on the docs, where "on" would be the last method call. But since not even **ensure** is working, I got stucked.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Aurelia went through a lot of changes in the last two years, so there are quite a few tutorials that don't work.  But the official documentation on DocHub for Aurelia Validation should work for you.  http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics

Comment: btw, you should accept @lstarky's answer.. b/c his is right, and mine is wrong :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aurelia went through a lot of changes in the last two years, so there are quite a few tutorials that don't work.  But the [official documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics) on DocHub for Aurelia Validation should work for you.

**Important note:**

Aurelia Validation seems to have a limitation that it doesn't work well with the sub-properties of an object, like you're trying to do (`this.movie.title`).  Instead, you should do something like this:

```
import {ValidationRules} from "aurelia-validation";
export class Edit {
  constructor() {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure("title").required()
      .ensure("releaseYear").required()
      .on(this.movie);
  }
}
```

You can change `.required()` to any of the valid rules.  However, I don't think that `.isNotEmpty()` or `.isNumber()` are on the list of valid rules.  See the documentation.

Comment: Alright, now that I've managed to get my question deleted by flagging my own answer, please accept this answer as correct!

Comment: I had to change `isnotEmpty()` to `required()` (close enough) and `isNumber()` to `matches(regex)`.